# broken image PHP (GD)

Tags: php, image, web, gd

My image looks like this:

[image]

Its getting the image from antibot.php

Here is my antibot.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $width      = 75;
    $height     = 40;
    $length     = 3;
    $baseList   = '1234567890';
    $code       = "";
    $counter    = 0;
    $image      = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Kunne ikke velge GD!');

    for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
       imageline($image, 
             mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 
             mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 
             imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(150,255), 
                                        mt_rand(150,255), 
                                        mt_rand(150,255)))) or die('Kunne ikke velge line!');
    }

    for($i=0, $x=0; $i<$length; $i++){
       $actChar = substr($baseList, rand(0, strlen($baseList)-1), 1);
       $x += 10 + mt_rand(0,10);
       imagechar($image, mt_rand(3,5), $x, mt_rand(5,20), $actChar, 
          imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(0,155), mt_rand(0,155), mt_rand(0,155)))) or die('Kunne ikke velge GD2!');
       $code .= strtolower($actChar)) or die('Kunne ikke velge GD3!');
    }

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
    $_SESSION['securityCode'] = $code;
?>
```

I have installed GD and freetype, could anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Why go through all that trouble of reinventing the wheel. Using captcha is just _way_ easier, if you ask me. It's all been done before...

Comment: Open the image URI in the browser and paste the output, please. You probably have a syntax error in your second *for* loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image wont show (PHP and GD)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300535/image-wont-show-php-and-gd). You've asked this exact question before. Sure, this time around you got a different error message, but that's coding for you. half of the time, it's about debugging, which is something you have to do yourself, this isn't a free debugger service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't have many problems. Remove the extra brackets at the end of the **imagecolorallocate** inside the **for** loops. It is just having some syntax errors.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $width      = 75;
    $height     = 40;
    $length     = 3;
    $baseList   = '1234567890';
    $code       = "";
    $counter    = 0;
    $image      = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Kunne ikke velge GD!');

    for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
       imageline($image, 
             mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 
             mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 
             imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(150,255), 
                                        mt_rand(150,255), 
                                        mt_rand(150,255))) or die('Kunne ikke velge line!'); 
    }

    for($i=0, $x=0; $i<$length; $i++){
       $actChar = substr($baseList, rand(0, strlen($baseList)-1), 1);
       $x += 10 + mt_rand(0,10);
       imagechar($image, mt_rand(3,5), $x, mt_rand(5,20), $actChar, 
          imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(0,155), mt_rand(0,155), mt_rand(0,155))) or die('Kunne ikke velge GD2!');
       $code .= strtolower($actChar) or die('Kunne ikke velge GD3!');
    }

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
    $_SESSION['securityCode'] = $code;
?>
```

But prefer to use something like [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) which is quite easier to implement and you can let your users contributing something to digitizing the books by using it.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell what you did change?:)

Comment: @MalinPedersen extra braces removed from **imagecolorallocate** functions calls.

Answer (score 1):

There's a syntax error, ComFreek is right:

```
   imagechar($image, mt_rand(3,5), $x, mt_rand(5,20), $actChar, 
      imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(0,155), mt_rand(0,155), mt_rand(0,155)))) or die('Kunne ikke velge GD2!');
//                                                                            /\4?
```

Has one closing parentheses too many, it should be

```
   imagechar($image, mt_rand(3,5), $x, mt_rand(5,20), $actChar, 
      imagecolorallocate($image, mt_rand(0,155), mt_rand(0,155), mt_rand(0,155))) or die('Kunne ikke velge GD2!');
//                                                                       3 is enough
```

Oh and *please*, don't use `or die`. If there's an error, fix it. Don't use a pointless `or die` message. Let PHP show the errors (*as in line X: Unexpected )*).
Also: don't use the `@` error supressing operator. If there's an error: Fix it, don't cover it up. Have your ini set to `E_STRICT | E_ALL` and display errors set to 1, and work at your code until it's notice-free.

```
$image      = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Kunne ikke velge GD!');
//should be:
$image = imagecreate($width, $height);
```

It makes your code more readable, and if something goes wrong, at least you stand a better chance to actually know what to fix. Something like *"Kunne ikke velge GD!"* is about as meaningless as *"Something didn't quite work... no idea what or where"*